# How to write a task in ansible so that they perform the same thing as docker build and docker run

Tags: docker, ansible

I searched the forum but couldn't find anything. Poke your finger if that)
How to write a task in ansible so that they perform the same thing as:

```
docker build. -t alpine: volume
docker run --rm -ti -v colibri:/colibri alpine: volume
```

which will create a docker image for me and connect the volume so that the files are synced there.
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk add unzip && \
    addgroup -S -g 9999 www && \
    adduser -u 9999 -S -G www www && \
    mkdir /colibri && chown www:www /colibri

COPY artifact.zip /colibri/artifact.zip
USER www
WORKDIR colibri
RUN unzip artifact.zip && rm artifact.zip
```

task in ansible:

```
- name: Build image
  community.docker.docker_image:
    build:
      path: "{{ remote_path }}/docker/volume"
    name: volume
    tag: v1
    push: no
    source: build
    
  - name: Build an volume on artefact
  community.docker.docker_container:
    name: volume:v1
    state: present
    volumes:
      - colibri:/colibri
    cleanup: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question myself. Through tests and errors, I arrived at this result

```
- name: Build an image
  community.docker.docker_image:
    build:
      path: "{{ remote_path }}/docker/volume"
    name: volume
    tag: v1
    source: build

- name: Build an artefact on volume
  community.docker.docker_container:
    name: volume
    image: volume:v1
    state: started
    timeout: 300
    volumes:
      - colibri_magento:/colibri
    auto_remove: yes
    cleanup: yes
```